# iOS How do I add a new item to a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

So I have a CollectionView as my home view, then I have a second view as a table view controller that adds a single image to itself. As soon as I press the “save” button on the top right I get the error code: [See image of what I'm trying to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR6Iu.jpg)

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have a model of array items that take in only images. How can I pass my uploaded image to my CollectionView from my Table View and update the CollectionView with the uploaded item

This is where the error occurs:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let uploadedImage = uploadImageView.image {
        items.image = uploadedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Add more code here. These are 2 controllers and you need to pass data between them?

Answer (score 1):

You get this issue when you're force unwrapping an optional and it's actually empty. Try:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let uploadedImage = uploadImageView?.image {
        items.image = uploadedImage
    } else {
        print("uploadImageView is nil check the @IBOutlet connection for uploadImageView!!!")
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this problem i suggest you to use guard to made sure your optional variable is not nil

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let uploadedImage = uploadImageView.image else {
        //do something if nill here
        return
    }
    items.image = uploadedImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This removed the crash! Thanks. Now how do I update the collection view to include the new item?

Comment: just reload the data using yourCollectionNode.reloadData(), it should show the new item.

Comment: where do I put collectionView.reloadData() ? I tried putting it on my MainCollectionViewController inside the viewWillAppear() method but nothing really happened..

Comment: can you show me the code? or you can made another thred to ask this question since it might be to small.